# Flot multiple stacked series in one chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, series, stacked

Is it possible to have two separate data variables to be stacked separately on the same chart? So for example, my first data variable has 3 stacked series in it and my second data variable has 2 different stacked series in it. Can I have both of them in the same chart, but stacked independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand, but if you want two groups of stacks, just separate them out on the x-axis:

```
    var d1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
        d1.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);
    }

    var d2 = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
        d2.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);
    }

    var d3 = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
        d3.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);
    }

    // d1, d2, d3 run 0 to 10
    // d4, d5, 12 to 20

    var d4 = [];
    for (i = 12; i <= 20; i += 1) {
        d4.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);
    }       

    var d5 = [];
    for (i = 12; i <= 20; i += 1) {
        d5.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);
    }
```

Produces (example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KQJasJOtsz3w3qxGiEVK?p=preview)):

[image]

**EDIT FOR COMMENTS**

If you want to stack some series in the positive direction and others in the negative, provide a unique `stack` variable value for each stack group.

```
    var d1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
        d1.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);
    }
    d1 = {data: d1, stack: 1}; // specifiy a unique stack for pos

    var d2 = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
        d2.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);
    }
    d2 = {data: d2, stack: 1}; // specifiy a unique stack for pos

    var d3 = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
        d3.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);
    }
    d3 = {data: d3, stack: 1}; // specifiy a unique stack for pos

    var d4 = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
        d4.push([i, parseInt(-Math.random() * 30)]);
    }
    d4 = {data: d4, stack: 2}; // specifiy a unique stack for neg


    var d5 = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
        d5.push([i, parseInt(-Math.random() * 30)]);
    }
    d5 = {data: d5, stack: 2}; // specifiy a unique stack for neg
```

Updated [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dJXhtcMP3qRPMZ4lyKsV?p=preview).

[image]